# I've created an animation that slides out social media icons. However, I need to apply this to multiple divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a website and I have multiple images *(seven in total)*.

**For each image**, I need a button to appear when the image is hovered.

**The button** is a small .png image of a plus-sign *(+)*.

When the button is **clicked**:

- the button image changes to a horizontal line
- Social media icons slide in to the right.

I have it working perfectly on one image. The problem is, when I apply the same JavaScript code to the other images, it doesn't work. I tried changing all of my ID's to Classes, but still no good. How can I get this to work?

Below is my code and can be seen at: [http://box5385.temp.domains/~atelifw5/test-2/](http://box5385.temp.domains/%7Eatelifw5/test-2/)

```js
// Controls social media reveal animation
function myFunction() {
  console.log("Button clicked");

  var img = document.getElementById("cross.img");
  var x = document.getElementById("hidden-social");

  x.addEventListener("animationend", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (x.style.animationName == "slide-left") {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
  });

  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    x.style.animation = "1s slide-right";

    img.src = "http://box5385.temp.domains/~atelifw5/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/horiz.thin_.png";
  } else {
    x.style.animation = "1s slide-left";

    img.src = "http://box5385.temp.domains/~atelifw5/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/cross.thin_.png";
  }
}

// Controls the cross-button so fading image
// stays faded when cross-button is hovered
document.getElementById("cross-button").onmouseover = function() {
  mouseOver()
};

document.getElementById("cross-button").onmouseout = function() {
  mouseOut()
};

function mouseOver() {
  document.getElementById("fading-image").style.opacity = "0.5";
}

function mouseOut() {
  document.getElementById("fading-image").style.opacity = "1";
}

// Controls the fading image, so it remains
// faded after hover-off of cross-button
document.getElementById("fading-image").onmouseover = function() {
  mouseOver()
};

document.getElementById("fading-image").onmouseout = function() {
  mouseOut()
};

function mouseOver() {
  document.getElementById("fading-image").style.opacity = "0.5";
}

function mouseOut() {
  document.getElementById("fading-image").style.opacity = "1";
}

// Controls the cross-button, so it is visible when the
// hidden-social container is hovered
document.getElementById("hidden-social-container").onmouseover = function() {
  mouseOver()
};

document.getElementById("hidden-social-container").onmouseout = function() {
  mouseOut()
};

function mouseOver() {
  document.getElementById("fading-image").style.opacity = "0.5";
  document.getElementById("cross-button").style.opacity = "1.0";
}

function mouseOut() {
  document.getElementById("fading-image").style.opacity = "1";
  document.getElementById("cross-button").style.opacity = "0";
}
```

```css
/*Fade image*/

#container {
  overflow: auto;
}

#cross-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: -55px;
  left: -54%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 32px;
  float: right;
}

#fading-image>img {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  width: auto;
}

#fading-image:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

#fading-image:hover~#cross-button,
#cross-button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.social-icon-2 {
  width: 25px;
}

.social-icon-p2 {
  width: 15px;
}

#hidden-social-container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 32px;
  position: relative;
  top: -52px;
  left: -48%;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
}

#hidden-social-container:hover~#cross-button,
#cross- button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#hidden-social {
  width: auto;
}

@keyframes slide-right {
  from {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}

@keyframes slide-left {
  from {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!--- HTML --->
<div id="cross-container">
  <div id="fading-image">
    <img src="http://box5385.temp.domains/~atelifw5/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/RO_PIX_EV_03_1320px.png">
  </div>

  <div id="cross-button" onclick="myFunction()">
    <img id="cross.img" src="http://box5385.temp.domains/~atelifw5/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/cross.thin_.png">
  </div>
  <div id="hidden-social-container">
    <div id="hidden-social" style="display:none;">
      <a href="https://instagram.com" target="blank">
        <img class="social-icon-2" src="http://box5385.temp.domains/~atelifw5/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/Instagram_Black.svg">
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://box5385.temp.domains/~atelifw5/east-village" target="blank">
        <img class="social-icon-2" src="http://box5385.temp.domains/~atelifw5/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/Facebook_Black.svg">
      </a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=http://box5385.temp.domains/~atelifw5/east-village/" target="_blank">
        <img class="social-icon-2" src="http://box5385.temp.domains/~atelifw5/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/Facebook_Black.svg">
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url=http://box5385.temp.domains/~atelifw5/east-village" target="blank">
        <img class="social-icon-2" src="http://box5385.temp.domains/~atelifw5/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/LinkedIn_Black.svg">
      </a>
      <a href="https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/" target="blank">
        <img class="social-icon-p2" src="http://box5385.temp.domains/~atelifw5/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/Pinterest_Black.svg">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you just want to apply the CSS to multiple HTML elements, use CSS classes or selectors like `#id-one, #id-two, #id-three {}`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors?retiredLocale=de See also JavaScript: `getElementsByClassName`, `querySelector`

Comment: Thank you for your input Pinke. Unfortunately, I am in need of a more comprehensive response. The solution here is within the Javascript and not just CSS.  I do believe you are correct that it is through the use of getElementsByClassName and querySelector, but I have been unable to modify the HTML and Javascript to do this, due to my lack of knowledge in Javascript.

Comment: @MCSquared You could [edit] the question to clarify the specific help that you needs. i.e. you could [edit] the question to include what was said in the previous comments. This could be done by including a section about what you have tried describing were you get stuck. Also you might make the question more specific about the answer that you need,i.e. how to use javascript to do X. Note: If this question become obsolete because your recent questions, you should add a a note in your newest questions saying that they are follow-up questions derived from this one.

Comment: 1) Is the space in `cross- button:hover` intentional? 2) HTML comments only need two dashes (`<!-- -->`).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have repeating of the hidden-social-container for each image,  give each image an unique id (id="cross.img-1") and  also fo the div (id="hidden-social-container-1"). Send the ids for them to the function.

html:

```
<div id="cross-button" onclick="myFunction("cross.img-1", "hidden-social-container-1" )">
```

javascript:

```
function myFunction(imgId, divId) {
var img = document.getElementById(imgId);
var x = document.getElementById(divId);
...
}
```